# Django cart with user defined attributes

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Good day.

I'm building an application for ordering prints and struggles at a part where 
the user, apart from selecting from predefined values, can enter her own data for printing.

Consider the following:

```
class PrintItem(models.Model):
    """ Something printable. Poster, t-shirt, mug, etc """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class AttributeType(models.Model):
    """ Size,colour, etc """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Attribute(models.Model):
    """ Size: A4, A5 | Colour: Violet, Black """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type = models.ForeignKey(AttributeType)

# And a join model
class PrintAttribute(models.Model):
    print_item = models.ForeignKey(PrintItem)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute)

# The user adds these to a cart
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
    print_item = models.ForeignKey(PrintItem)
```

This works all good. The user can select from the predefined attributes, but how and where would you suggest I would implement the user input functionality?
User finds an item to print, chooses from the predefined Attributes (print size, the ink colour) and can enter her own message/slogan to print on the item.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: I would suggest you think again about you model structure first. Seems quite confusing for me. Three models should be enough: `PrintItem(name, attributes[m2m])`, `Attribute(name, type)` and `CartItem(user[foreign], print_item[foreign])`. Might be, I overlooked something, but you should be able to express the same relationships with these three Models so much easier.

Comment: ``AttributeType`` is to allow creation of types unknown during development. The admin might want to add and remove types. Perhaps the ``Cart `` could be merged with ``CartItem``. However my main problem is where to store user inputted data for an attribute. Updating question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user's own slogan/message gets entered only upon adding a print item to the cart, then the slogan/message should be a field of `CartItem`.

Comment: I do believe you're right. It's along the line of my thinking.

Comment: Flagging this as the correct answer as it's the approach I'm going for. Many thanks for leading me in the right direction.